# Разница между словами "эскапада" и "эпатаж"

Tags: лексикон, выбор-слова

Слово **эпатаж**, которое словари определяют как

> Поведение, намеренно нарушающее общепринятые нормы и правила;
>   скандальная выходка.

встречается отностельно часто в речи.

Слово **эскапада** встречается значительно реже. Обозначает оно, судя по словарю, примерно то же самое, что и эпатаж:

> Экстравагантная выходка.

В чем разница между этими словами? И как определяться, выбирая между ними?

Comment: Кажется, этот вопрос лучше задать здесь: http://rus.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The main meaning of *эпатаж* is intentionally scandalous behaviour. Its meaning of "individual intentionally scandalous action" is metonymic and quire rarely (if ever) used. It's almost never used in plural.

*Эскапада* can only mean an individual shocking action, with its scandalousness not necessarily intentional. It's synonymous with *выходка* (which is actually its Russian calque).

Compare:

> - ― Пожалуйста, не принимайте за эпатаж то, что я беседую с вами в одном белье. *[Виктор Пелевин. Чапаев и пустота (1996)]*
> - Отсчет ведется поступков идиотских, безумных выходок и эскапад невероятных, короче, сплетен, домыслов, досужих разговоров, легенд и мифов. *[Сергей Солоух. Клуб одиноких сердец унтера Пришибеева (1991-1995)]*

Comment: Why can't we use "принимайте за **эскападу**" in the first example?

Comment: @ovgolovin: because it's already an *эскпада*. The protagonist wanted to say that it wasn't his goal to shock.

Comment: So, эпатаж consists of a series of эксапад. But unlike эпатаж, one paticular эскапада doesn't not necessary imply being **intentionally** scandalous. Right?

Comment: If so, the usage of эпатаж in the first example may be explained as an intention to carry the idea of that action not being **intentionally** scandalous, because if the author had used "эскапада", it wouldn't make much sense as (as you wrote) this action is эскапада, not intentional though.

Comment: @ovgolovin: right (both).

Answer (score 0):

`Эпатаж` происходит от épater (é + patter), на французском означает впечатлить (буквально "дать пинка").

`Эскапада` - от романского (фр. или исп.) `escapar`, убегать или выбегать.

В русском слово "выходка" смысл отражает ясно, а заимствования со временем размывают смысл или дрейфуют. Но здесь они пока отражают разницу:

- эпатаж - это результат
- эскапада - это действие

Comment: Ну в фразе "отсюда весь его эпатаж" речь всё-таки о действии а не о результате

Comment: @shabunc значение дрейфует.